# Assinar o apk Android

Tags: apache-cordova

Boa noite pessoal!

Estou tentando assinar um *apk* de teste mas não estou conseguindo.

Tentei no Linux e Mac e o retorno é a mesma mensagem:

> jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: testeapp.  testeapp must
>   reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and
>   corresponding public key certificate chain.

Estou criando a keystore desta forma:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore testechave.keystore -alias 
testechave -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Colocando tudo dentro do mesmo diretório (apk e testechave.keystore) e executando o comando:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1
-keystore testechave.keystore
testeapp-unsigned.apk testeapp
```

É nesse momento que gera essa mensagem e nada faz!
Estou fazendo algo erro?
Minha versão do cordova é 5.0

Comment: no jarsigner tenta sem o testeapp no final

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Thiago. Mas não deu certo.
Retorno:
Please specify alias name

Comment: Consegue resolver.
keytool -genkey -v -keystore testechave.keystore -alias 
testechave -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

O nome do alisas é testechave, e ele precisa ser informado logo abaixo.

jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1
-keystore testechave.keystore
testeapp-unsigned.apk testechave

Feito isso fica tudo ok!

Comment: Poste a solução em uma resposta e não dentro da pergunta, não somos um fórum, somo um Q&A, somos diferentes de outros sites, veja o tour: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour